# AspectJ: how to get a Thread name?

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j, aspectj

I need to get Thread names and log them in AspectJ class. This solution does't work

```
`@Around("call(void method*())")  
public Object condition(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable 
{   
    PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object res = joinPoint.proceed();
    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - before;

    logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "\t" + diff ); 

    return res;
}
```

`
because the result is e.g.:

`main  717`

My aspect is `around` some methods. How to get name of thread where method is executed (not thread created by aspect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** First of all its **Not the thread where method is execute**, But **the thread that executes the method.**

**2.** Here what you can do to **identify** the thread that **executed** that method:

**- Initialize the thread.**

```
    Thread t = new Thread(MyClass);
```

// MyClass is the class which extends or implements Thread or Runnable respectively.

**- Naming the thread of execution.**

```
   t.setName("T1");
```

**- Inside the method getting the thread that is executing it.**

```
   public void go(){

     Thread.currentThread().getName();

  }
```

Comment: I see my mistake. But I still cannot resolve my problem. There is methodA in ThreadA and my methodB in ThreadB (B in AspectJ class) which is `@around` methodA. How to get ThreadA name in methodB?

Comment: Well its like this... methodA cannot be in ThreadA but in class A, and methodB  cannot be ThreadB but in class B. Now Thread from class A can access the method in class B, and vice versa.. then its as it is, as i have mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
**You can setName() method** 



  //get currently running thread object
                Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
                System.out.println(currentThread);

                /*
                 * To set name of thread, use
                 * void setName(String threadName) method of
                 * Thread class.
                 */

                currentThread.setName("Set Thread Name Example");



public void run() {
  System.out.println(th.getName()+" is starting.....");
  System.out.println("Current thread name : "+
  Thread.currentThread().getName());
  }
```

Comment: how is it connected with aspect? I cannot see how I can get inside the aspect that way.

Answer (score 0):

it seams for me that the current thread of execution is **main** thread which is currentThread. If you want to dump all threads, use this:

```
 public static String getDumpFor(Thread thread) {
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder();
    if (thread.isAlive()) {
        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = thread.getStackTrace();
        st.append(thread.toString()).append("\n")
                .append(String.format(" State - %s,", thread.getState()))
                .append(String.format(" Is daemon = %s,", thread.isDaemon()));
        for (StackTraceElement s : stackTrace)
            st.append("\tat ").append(s.getClassName()).append(".").append(s.getMethodName()).append("(").append(s.getFileName()).append(":").append(s.getLineNumber()).append(")")
                    .append("\n");
    } else {
        st.append(" No thread ");
    }
    return st.toString();
}

/**
 * print thread dump for each active thread over logger API.
 */
public static void dumpActiveThreads() {
    Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> stackTraces = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    Set<Thread> keySet = stackTraces.keySet();
    System.out.println("\nThread dump begin:");
    for (Thread thread : keySet)
        dumpActiveThread(thread);
    System.out.println("\nThread dump end.");

}
```

However i still may missunderstood the question "How to get real Thread name?"...

Comment: I'll try to be more specific: I am looking for a name of thread where method is executed, not a thread created by aspect. In need thread name inside the joinPoint.

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you are creating thread set their name in the format you want like below otherwise it will give the default assigned name.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    Thread.currentThread().setName("My Main Thread");

    Thread t1=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());

        }
    });
    t1.setName("t1 thread");
    System.out.println("Thread : "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    t1.start();
}
```

**Result:**

```
Thread : main
Thread : My Main Thread
Thread : t1 thread
```

Comment: I am looking for a name of thread where method is executed, not thread created by aspect. Your solution doesn't go _inside_ the aspect

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried to reproduce the threading situation, but I guess another approach might be more helpful in your situation: You could combine your `around` advice with introduction (a.k.a. [inter-type declarations](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#inter-type-declarations)). Declare a member storing the thread information you want to extract in the `Runnable` classes of interest or maybe in the classes called by them and access that information in your logging advice.

**Edit:** You might want to use a `ThreadLocal` for storing the information. ;-)

**Edit 2:** Have you tried to use an `execution()` pointcut instead of a `call()` pointcut in order to be in the executing context and probably get the running thread directly without any tricks?